# QLineEdit destroyed before his parent

Tags: c++, qt

i'm having some trouble executing this code:

```
void WidgetAggiungi::btnAggiungi_click(){
QDate data=editData->date();

if (radioTelefonata->isChecked()){
    QString numTemp=txtNumero->text();
    ...
}
```

When i try to access txtNumero i got a segmentation fault.
txtNumero is a QLineEdit decleared as a private member of WidgetAggiungi.
What bothers me is that the QDateEdit editData works fine even if it's decleared and created in the same way of txtNumero.

All the code of WidgetAggiungi is on github: https://github.com/GiacomoManzoli/qdb/blob/master/widgetaggiungi.h https://github.com/GiacomoManzoli/qdb/blob/master/widgetaggiungi.cpp

Answer (score 2):

you declared `txtNumero` on the header file. but then in the constructor you did :
`QLineEdit* txtNumero = new ...` so you are not initializing the txtNumero on the header. that's why it gave you segfault..

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor:

```
QLineEdit* txtNumero = new QLineEdit();
```

You are declaring a local variable, not instanciating your class member. Just remove the type at the beginning:

```
txtNumero = new QLineEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems one of which is serious, the other is a minor memory leak:

Firstly, you created the `QLineEdit` like this:

```
    QLineEdit* txtNumero= new QLineEdit();
```

that is creating a **local** variable named `txtNumero` and not assigning it to the class member. You should write this instead:

```
txtNumero= new QLineEdit();
```

It appears that you have made this mistake in a few places. You should apply a similar fix to all of them.

Also, you should pass the parent to the constructors so they will automatically get cleaned up. Like this:

```
txtNumero= new QLineEdit(this);
```

Hope this helps!